# JSONDecodeError encountered when loading data with pandas_datareader

Tags: json, pandas, pandas-datareader, yfinance

```
import json
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import yfinance as yf
yf.pdr_override()
style.use('ggplot')
start = dt.datetime(2020,1,1)
end = dt.datetime.now()
df = web.get_data_yahoo('AMD', start, end)
df1 = json.load(df)
print(df1)
```

the error

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\monst\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\monst\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\monst\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\multitasking\__init__.py", line 102, in _run_via_pool
    return callee(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\monst\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\yfinance\multi.py", line 168, in _download_one_threaded
    actions, period, interval, prepost, proxy, rounding)
  File "C:\Users\monst\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\yfinance\multi.py", line 183, in _download_one
    rounding=rounding, many=True)
  File "C:\Users\monst\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\yfinance\base.py", line 157, in history
    data = data.json()
  File "C:\Users\monst\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 900, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\monst\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\monst\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\monst\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

i update the pandas_datareader to 0.7 and my pandas to 0.24.1 but it's still happen please can explain what is happening here and also ir try this method .json() and to_json() but nothing is working

```
amd = yf.Ticker("amd")
amd_price = amd.history(period="max")
amd_Volume = amd_price["Volume"]
amd_Volume = amd_Volume.reset_index()
amd_Volume = pd.DataFrame(amd_Volume)
print(amd_Volume)
amd_Volume = amd_Volume.sort_values(by="Volume")
print(amd_Volume.tail(1))
```

see this code it give me the same error why?

Comment: Thanks so much for posting a complete example with your question! made it really easy to debug.

Answer (score 0):

The [pandas-datareader get_data API](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_data.html) returns [pandas.DataFrames](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html), not string json objects or files.

[json.load](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) expects a file object, not a DataFrame. The error you're getting is just saying that the JSON module expected a different object type.

You should be able to skip the last line and just use the dataframe `df`.

Comment: hello see the code the new code above thanke you